# Website about page is working improperly. Website is not responsive on other devices

Tags: html, css

I have made an about page for my class assignment. Everything worked fine until I used the inspect option to see if my webpage is responsive to other devices. It was not responsive, I tried to see what is wrong with the code but I could not find an error in my codes after 5 hrs. Help would be appreciated.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
.title12{
   text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.p1{
  text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

h1{
     
    text-align: center;
}

.h2{
    margin-top: 400px;
}

.reviews{
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 300px;
   
}


  
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  
  /* Float four columns side by side */
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  
  /* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
  .row {margin: 0 -5px;}
  
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  
  /* Responsive columns */
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    
    
    }
  }
  
  /* Style the counter cards */
  .card {
   
    padding: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
   
  }

  .re1{
      width: 250px;
  }

  .re3{
    width:250px;
    height: 350px;
  }

 

  .container2{
    display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items:justify;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 40px 20px 0 20px;
     margin-top: 80px;
   }

   .container2 .heading{
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .container2 .heading h3{
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  }
  
  .container2 .heading h3 span{
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .con2{
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-top: 900px;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 2 auto;

    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
nav{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 z-index: 99;
 background-color: black;
 padding: 16px 32px;
 border-bottom: 3px solid blue ;

}


.menu{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 0 -16px;
    flex: 1 1 0%;

}
.menu a{
    color: white;
    margin: 0 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    padding:8px 16px;
    border-radius: 90px;
}
.menu a.highlight, .menu a:hover{
    background-color:red;
}

a{
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}





 body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  video {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    
  }
 
.normal{
      width: 100%;
    
  }
  .footer{
      padding: 40px 0;
      background-color: black;
    
    

  }
  .footer .social{
      text-align: center;
      padding-bottom: 25px;
      color: white;

  }
  .footer .social a{
      font-size: 24px;
      color: white;
      border: 1px solid white;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 38px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 0 8px;
      opacity: 0.75;
  }
  .footer .social a:hover{
      opacity: 0.9;
  }
 .footer ul{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;

 }
 .footer ul li a{
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     opacity: 0.8;

 }
 .footer ul li{
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 0 15px;

 }
 .footer ul li a:hover{
     opacity: 1;
     color: red;
 }
 .footer .copy{
     margin-top: 15px;
     text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: white;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="about.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/57160f5774.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="about.css">
   
    
    <title>About Us</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav>
        <div class="container">
          
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="main.html" class="highlight">Home</a>
            <a href="products.html">Products</a>
            <a href="pc designs.html">PC Designs</a>
            <a href="https://www.asus.com/lk/support/">Support</a>
            <a href="https://pcpartpicker.com/list/">Build Your PC</a>
        </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
  
    <img style="float: left; height: 750px;" src  ="About us/V388-SUPRIM.png">
    <div class="title12">
    <h1>SUPRIMX</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="p1">
    <p>SUPRIMX is a world leader in gaming, content creation, business & productivity and AIoT solutions. </p>
    <p>Bolstered by its cutting-edge R&D capabilities and customer-driven innovation, SUPRIMX has a wide-ranging global presence spanning over 120 countries. Its comprehensive lineup of laptops, graphics cards, monitors, motherboards, desktops, peripherals, and telematics systems are globally acclaimed.</p> 
    </div>

   
 
 
   <div class="reviews">
    
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="heading">
          <h3>Reviews<span>  </span></h3>
        </div>
        </div>
    
  
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
          <h3><img class="re1" src="About us/kayla.jpg"></h3>
          <br>
          <p>Kayla </p>
          <br>
          <p>
            Amazing website to buy a lot of products!.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <br>
            <br>
          <h3><img class="re2" src="About us/Curtis.jpg"></h3>
          <br>
          <p>Curtis</p>
          <br>
          <p>5 stars!!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
          <h3><img class="re3" src="About us/Tyler.jpg"></h3>
          <br>
          <p>Tyler</p>
          <br>
          <p>Incredible website!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
     
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    
    <section class="footer">
        <div class="social">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="list">
            <li>
                <a href="main.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="About.html">About SUPRIMX</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="https://linustechtips.com/">Forums</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="products.html">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="https://www.asus.com/lk/support/">Support</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p class="copy">
            SUPRIMX &copy 2022
        </p>
    </section>


  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `media query` for all devices.

Comment: make sure to put your media query at the bottom of your CSS file. CSS is read from top to bottom

Comment: Use media query or CSS flexbox to make responsive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)